# How can I list MediaWiki users added by date?

Tags: mediawiki

The **Special:ListUsers** page allows me to view all the users in MediaWiki. Is it possible to view them by date added?

(I'm sure I've done this before, but maybe it was via an extension.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the **Special:ListUsers** page is standard functionality but only with a later version of MediaWiki than what we currently have.

Wikipedia, for example, does have this [particular functionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:ListUsers&dir=prev&creationSort=1) in place.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228789/what-can-i-do-when-a-post-ive-written-receives-a-lot-of-spam-edits if this continues in the future.

Comment: Can you remember what version you were using at the time?

Comment: I've added all of the information that I can think of, but expanding on this answer would be to your advantage.